# Zip files need to include empty folders

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I currently have this directory structure:

```
upload-here
upload-here/258/Image1.jpg
upload-here/259/Image2.jpg
upload-here/260/NO IMAGE
upload-here/261/somepicturename.jpg
```

etc etc. I am using the code shown below to make a backup of the upload-here folder by zipping it up.

```
<?php
// Get real path for our folder
$rootPath = realpath('/full-path-to/upload-here/');

// Initialize archive object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('upload-here.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// Create recursive directory iterator
/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$file->isDir())
    {
        // Get real and relative path for current file
        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }
}
// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();
?>
```

This works fine with only one issue: if a folder does not have an image inside it, the folder is not backed up.

How can I tweak the code so that it zips up empty folders as well (so the exact structure matches what is online)?

===================
added

```
echo "<Br>". $filePath . "<br>".  $relativePath . "<br>".  $name ;
```

before last two }. This gives:

```
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here

/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/.
/home/fullpath/public_html

/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/..
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/73
73
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/73/.
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here

/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/73/..
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/283
283
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/283/.
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here

/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/283/..
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/284
284
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/284/.
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here

/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/284/..
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/291
291
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/291/.
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here

/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/291/..
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/292
292
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here/292/.
/home/fullpath/public_html/upload-here
```

etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try it. You can get the zip file including the empty folders.

```
foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
$filePath = $file->getRealPath();
$relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);
// Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
if (!$file->isDir()) {
    // Add current file to archive
    $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
} else {
    if($relativePath !== false)
        $zip->addEmptyDir($relativePath);
}}
```

Comment: Cool, glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the folder is empty, and then use [addEmptyDir()][1] to add it to the archive:

```
    foreach ($files as $name => $file)
    {
     $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
     $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$file->isDir())
    {
        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    } else {
        if(count(glob($name."/*")) == 0) {
           $zip->addEmptyDir(basename($name));
    }
  }
}

  [1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addemptydir.php
```

Comment: Still seems to be skipping the empty folders (just tested and the zip only contained folders with files, no empty folders;

Comment: have you tried both $relativePath and $filePath? And is the $name variable containing only a file name or a full path? I also edited the code, I missed a negation in a condition. So see the edits

Comment: Thanks for your help, sadly the above now results in an empty zip file

Comment: The only variables used are the ones shown here etc

Comment: @user6796243 I made some changes to the code, try it now.
Also, I understand that they are only variables used, but I wanted to know their values.

Comment: Hi, script works again but is skipping the empty folders. When I set the $name variable to be echo'd it gives "/home/full-pathetc/public_html/upload-here/1091/" (where 1091 is the last folder created)

Comment: print out and send me values of these variables in the loop: $filePath, $relativePath, $name

Comment: I edited the code based on the value on $name. It was a full path, now it should create a new empty folder in dir if !$file->isDir()

Comment: added echo 'filePath ='. $filePath . '<br>relativePath ='. $relativePath . '<br>name ='. $name ; which gives 

filePath =/home/full-path/public_html/upload-here
relativePath =
name =/home/full-path/public_html/upload-here/.filePath =/home/full-path/public_html

Comment: Tested and new zip sadly still doesn't have the empty folders included

Comment: added the output above (hopefully this helps??) Thanks again for your help with this.